# Flask restful and flask jwt - How to use together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restful, flask-jwt

I am using flask restful for my API server, and would like to use flask_jwt in order to secure my endpoints.

This is my endpoint and how I add those to the API server

```
class Model(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return 1 

api.add_resource(Model, '/path')
```

I would like to add a simple `@jet_required` decorator for my API endpoint. How can I get something that is similar to this

```
@app.route('/protected')
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return '%s' % current_identity
```

But using flask restful interface?

When I try to use the following, and accessing the endpoint I get this error

class Model(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
            return 1

> TypeError: .wrapper..decorator
>   at 0x7ff5fb262840> is not JSON serializable
>   127.0.0.1 - - [22/Jan/2020 10:10:28] "GET /resize HTTP/1.1" 500

Answer (score 0):

Made it work using flask_jwt_extended, as in [this](https://codeburst.io/jwt-authorization-in-flask-c63c1acf4eeb) example

Using the following code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'jwt-secret-string'
jwt = JWTManager(app)

@app.route('/protected')
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return '%s' % current_identity
```

That now returns a graceful message in cases of missing authentication header.